# Operations with np.newaxis in Keras layers: multiply vs concatenation

Tags: python, keras, concatenation

I have a question about np.newaxis in Keras. I have a x_6 with dimension [None,64], which I can extend to 4 dimensions with

```
temp = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:])(x_6)
```

A multiplication with a layer x_1 with size (None,None,None,64) works

```
x_1 = Multiply()([x_1,temp])
```

But a concatenation of the two of them doesn't work because of non-matching shapes

```
x_1 = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x_1,temp])
```

Does anyone see what the problem is?
The error message is

```
ValueError: A 'Concatenate' layer requires inputs with matching shapes excpet for the concat axis. Got input shapes: [(None,None,None,64),(None,1,1,64)]
```

Changing np.newaxis by None gives the same issue.

Another trick which didn't work

```
temp = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,axis=1))(x_6)
temp = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x,axis=1))(temp)
```

Comment: If the `None` are all 1 beside the batch then what about specific the shape in `Input`?

Comment: The Input has shape (None,None,3) as the dimensions of the input images is unknown.

Comment: Wait, then you can't concat if the shape is not equal, just like the traceback said.

Comment: Why can I multiply then?

Comment: It must be like `(None,None,None,64)` and `(None,None,None,12)` to concat with `axis=-1` and you will get a `(None,None,None,76)`

Comment: How can I create the Nones instead of 1's for the dimensions to expand?

Comment: I'm changing the answer above

Comment: It must be like (None,112,112,64) and (None,112,112,12) to concat with axis=-1 and you will get a (None,112,112,76)

Comment: You must have the same shape, even if both're None. The concept of concat a rank 4 tensor by rank 2 is probably wrong here

Comment: This boils down to multiply that does broadcasting while concatenate does not. So you just need a way to broadcast temp to the shape you want, which is [x_1.shape[0], x_1.shape[1], x_1.shape[2], temp.shape[3]] for concatenating along axis -1 (=3). This is probably possible somehow with tf.broadcast_to. Else, you can use multiply with all ones to do this broadcasting in an ugly way.